# Undefined in calculation with javascript

Tags: javascript

Everytime I run this code (var horizontal speed is a number, inserted by the user with a form) I get the word undefined followed by the text execute @e[type... etc.
I do not want the word undefined in the output as it also shows up in the textarea. What in my code is wrong that causes the word to appear??

```
function command(){
  var form = document.getElementById("form");                                           
  var horizontal_speed = form.elements["horizontal_speed"].value;
  for (var i = 1; i <= horizontal_speed; i ++){
    var standard_command = "execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=test] ~ ~ ~ /setblock etc particle insert_particle ~x_position ~1 ~z_position 0 0 0 0.01 1 force"
    var rad = (2*i*Math.PI)/horizontal_speed;
    var x_position = Math.round(Math.cos(rad) * 100) / 100;
    var z_position = Math.round(Math.sin(rad) * 100) / 100;




    var add_x_position = standard_command.replace('x_position', x_position);
    var add_z_position = add_x_position.replace('z_position', z_position);
    var output = output + add_z_position;
  }
  document.getElementById('output').value = output;
}
```

Comment: You have to initialize your output var.

Comment: You should debug your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var output = output + add_z_position;
```

On the first pass, `output` has never previously been assigned a value, and so it has `undefined`.

Move the `var` part above the loop and give it an initial value, probably `""`:

```
function command() {
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var horizontal_speed = form.elements["horizontal_speed"].value;
    var output = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= horizontal_speed; i++) {
        var standard_command = "execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=test] ~ ~ ~ /setblock etc particle insert_particle ~x_position ~1 ~z_position 0 0 0 0.01 1 force"
        var rad = (2 * i * Math.PI) / horizontal_speed;
        var x_position = Math.round(Math.cos(rad) * 100) / 100;
        var z_position = Math.round(Math.sin(rad) * 100) / 100;

        var add_x_position = standard_command.replace('x_position', x_position);
        var add_z_position = add_x_position.replace('z_position', z_position);
        output = output + add_z_position;
    }
    document.getElementById('output').value = output;
}
```

Separately,

```
output = output + add_z_position;
```

can be

```
output += add_z_position;
```

if you like.